# UITabBar disappears when NavigationController pop the view back to the said ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBar` on a `UIViewController`, attached from the Interface Builder, which is working fine, until I have a button that pushes another ViewController to the screen (ex: Login screen) via NavigationController.

After the other ViewController is popped, the screen returned to the original ViewController, but the TabBar is disappeared. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

use This in popped controller